# Recurrence Relation : Divisible Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, dynamic-programming

**Given an integer, n, find the smallest integer m such that is divisible by n (i.e.n,  is a factor of m ) and satisfies the following properties:**

1. **m** must not contain zeroes in its decimal representation.
2. The sum of **m's** digits must be greater than or equal to the product of **m's** digits.
   Given **n**, find the number of digits in **m's** decimal representation.

*Note: n is not divisible by 10.*

***How should I derive the Recurrence Relation for this problem?***

My approach: Suppose the n = 32, I am multiplying n by 1,2,3... and checking for the number at the units place if the number at the unit's place is greater than the largest digit of n and the number at the tens digit is greater than smallest digit of n then I ignore the m generated and move to the next multiplication.

I am not able to come up with the recurrence relation for doing this operation. Please Help! Thanks!

Comment: In your example, assuming 2-digit m are ruled out, then since m is even, 3-digit m must terminate in 4 if both of its first two digits = 1, or in 2 if only one of the first two digits = 1.  Only one in five multiples of 32 ends in 2: 192, 352, 512, 672, 832, 992; and one in five ends in 4: 224, 384, 544, 704, 864.   None meets the conditions on m.  4-digit m must have three 1's, or two 1's and 2,3 or 2,4 for the other two digits, since the product can't be > 8.  So again the terminal digit is 2 or 4: 1152, $1312$...  $1312$ is the least m for n = 32.  Is there a method in here somewhere?